# WCF Service Not working for Ajax Autocomplete extender

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

***"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.) localhost/WS/Service.svc/functionname"***

The above error is what i have been facing since last three days. Now I need to find out why isnt my WCF service not working in my web application.

My service.cs file lies in a **"CodeFiles"** named folder. Also service.svc file lies in folder named **"WS"**.

So Error comes every time when type some thing to search in my autocompleteextender which is using this service.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that the client is sending an "application/json" message, and the server is expecting "text/xml".  What you need to do is configure the server to accept json.  Googling for "WCF JSON" returns a number of links including [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec) which should help you on your way.